# how to lock a member function of a class which uses a constructor with an initialisation list

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is an excellent piece of code that addresses how to use a lock on member functions of an object.

```
 #include <thread>
 #include <mutex>
 #include <iostream>

 class Foo
 {
 public:
      void increment()
      {
         for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
         {
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); //lock mtx
              ++x;

             // mtx is automatically released when lock
             // goes out of scope -> RAII
         }
     }

     void decrement()
     {
           for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
           {
               std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); //lock mtx
               --x;

              // mtx is automatically released when lock
              // goes out of scope -> RAII
          }
        }

        static int x;
        static std::mutex mtx;
  };

   int Foo::x = 0;
   std::mutex Foo::mtx;

   int main()
   {
       std::thread t1(&Foo::increment, Foo());
       std::thread t2(&Foo::decrement, Foo());

       t1.join();
       t2.join();

       std::cout << Foo::x;
    }
```

My question is, how to implement this if the constructor has a data member initialization list. Is it possible?

Comment: I *think* you mean how to handle initializing some non-static member `y` that you would like to initialize with what would normally be something like `Foo() : y(x) {}`. Is *that* correct ?

Comment: BTW, for `int`, you may use `std::atomic` instead of `mutex`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an additional lock if `Foo` has data member initialization list as each thread has it's own instance of `Foo` class. [Member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) specifies the initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members.

You only need a `lock` to control the consistence of state shared between threads. Like static `Foo::x` in your sample.